# jquery http calls returning undefined in 2nd call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 `HTTP` requests, `function call1()` returns a `variable` I need to be used in `function2()`. The `return` value from `call1()` is defined however when `call1()` is triggered `path` in `call2()` it somehow become undefined.

```
call2(pageTitle); // call this function before call1()

function call1() {
    console.log('Before ajax call');
    var url = window.parent.__env.swaggerBaseUrl + 'api/Management/Configurations?name=ApiManagement';
    $.get(url).then(function(data) {
        if (data && data.Results && data.Results[0] && data.Results[0].Value) {
            console.log('If() I am here', data.Results[0].Value); // its defined
            return data.Results[0].Value;
        }
    })
}

function call2(pageTitle) {
    var path = call1();
    var url = path  + "Ewp/Definition?name=" + pageTitle.replace(/%20/g, ' ');
    console.log('EWP Data Path URL', url); // url is undefined
    $.get(url).then(function (data) {
        console.log('EWP Data in success', data);
        document.getElementById('xmlEWP').innerHTML = data.Results.Definition;
    })
}
```

Can someone point out why the `return data.Results[0].Value` is returning undefined in `call2()`. In my `console.log()` it fired `call2()` first which is correct according to the code above.

Comment: AJAX requests are asynchronous so you cannot return anything from them. Instead you need to work with the returned value within the callback function only. To fix your problem place `call(data.Results[0].Value)` in the callback of `$.get()` in `call1`. See the duplicate question I marked for more detailed information

Comment: so I can't just do a return and call `call1()` in `call2()`?

Comment: Oh nvm I totally missed the first line of your comment. Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to help